# CSS: fluid wrapper height depending on floated element

Tags: html, css, height, css-float

I know this is a question asked 12324 times probably, but I still can't find any reliable answers :/

Here is a sample code:
http://tinkerbin.com/c0wqtfSa

The wrap should take auto height depending on the float image, but how? :/

Thanks a lot!!!

ps, I can't add any extra div like "clear:both", it should be a solution only with css

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding

```
Overflow: auto;
```

to your wrapper div, example here: http://tinkerbin.com/pxFxaNX2

Comment: it looks like the solution!!! works fine on my Chrome. any issue with crossbrowsing? I need to find a windows machine to test :|

Comment: If you're going to use the overflow:auto... be sure to check out this posting about some of it's downfalls and how to fix them.

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-clearing-floats-with-overflow

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after your < p >

You need to clear after a floating element...

So:

```
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="imagefloat"></div>
      <p>sldkjfn asdhbf sdjlbhgls dhjbfg ljdshbfgl jsdbfgljh dsgf sgf</p>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `clear:both` like below:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="imagefloat"></div>
  <p>sldkjfn asdhbf sdjlbhgls dhjbfg ljdshbfgl jsdbfgljh dsgf sgf</p>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set overflow as well as width on your wrap div, e.g.

```
overflow:hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the clearfix workaround. Read this: http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

The css you need is:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
     display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

Then just add the clearfix class to your "wrap" div

Answer (score 0):

A very easy and quick fix it to make the wrap div also float. This will make it automatically change it size to all floated elements within in, so:

```
.wrap {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Whether this is an option for your project depends on the rest of the layout.